How to change the star colors of the TrustPilot review widget?
Guys I wonder if We can change the color of the star boxes in a TrustPilot rate review widget.
This is the widget I am using


<div  class="trustpilot-review-score">
    <div class="trustpilot-widget" 
    data-locale="en-US" 
    data-template-id="577258fb31fdsfsdsfdsfsdfewsdghh" 
    data-businessunit-id="56a27dfdsdsdfsdfse3000000587f4b4" 
    data-style-height="24px" 
    data-style-width="100%" 
    data-theme="light"
    data-sku="GRO-001"
    data-no-reviews="hide" 
    data-scroll-to-list="true" 
    data-style-alignment="left">  
        <a href="https://www.trustpilot.com/review/mycompany.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a> </div>
</div>    



And this is what I end up getting on the page


Found the answer by talking with one of the TrustPilot developers. You need to use the data-star-color attribute. Example:


<div  class="trustpilot-review-score">
    <div class="trustpilot-widget" 
    data-star-color="#006A8E" 
    data-locale="en-US" 
    data-template-id="577258fb31fdsfsdsfdsfsdfewsdghh" 
    data-businessunit-id="56a27dfdsdsdfsdfse3000000587f4b4" 
    data-style-height="24px" 
    data-style-width="100%" 
    data-theme="light"
    data-sku="GRO-001"
    data-no-reviews="hide"
    data-scroll-to-list="true" 
    data-style-alignment="left">  
        <a href="https://www.trustpilot.com/review/mycompany.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a> </div>
</div>    



